# Hibernate criteria builder subquery from a non-entity source

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a need to select from a non-entity subquery, a JSON table in this case, via Hibernate's criteria query.

For example:

```java
final var jsonTable = ...;
final var subquery = outerQuery.subquery(...);
final var root = subquery.from(jsonTable);
```

There are at least two issues here:

1. I'm not sure what to pass to `outerQuery.subquery()` since the subquery is going to be used in an `EXISTS` clause -- there is no real entity involved.
2. I have to pass either `Class<T>` or `EntityType<T>` to `subquery.from()`, but my `jsonTable` is of type `Expression<T>` as it's a function call.